# Default value is not passed to prop

Tags: vuejs3, prop

The code below should display my prop default value ("test") since it received no other value. Yet it displays nothing. Why not?

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ propValue }}
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
  import { defineProps } from "vue"

  const props = defineProps<{
    myProp: {
      type: string
      default: "test"
    }
  }>()

  const propValue = props.myProp
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons why.

1. When you use props with TypeScript you [lose the ability to set default values](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html#props-default-values), but it can be fixed using the `withDefaults` macro (you also need to separately declare a Props interface).  Side note: I would not use the alternative experimental "Reactivity Transform" solution noted in the docs (it's being removed soon)

```js
export interface Props {
  myProp?: string;
}

const props = withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {
  myProp: 'test'
});
```

2. This one isn't actually strictly necessary, but `props` is a reactive object, and when you assign a single property of `props` to a new variable, the reactivity breaks.  In order to maintain reactivity and stay synced with any future changes to props, use the [toRef](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-utilities.html#toref) function

```js
const propValue = toRef(props, 'myProp');
```

and be sure to import it: `import { defineProps, toRef } from 'vue';`